# regular notification wont show X close button in android

Tags: android, button, notifications, default

I created a notification using android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder. The notification shows up fine in the notification area.But it doesn't show the default close button on android 4.2.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)

As per the docuentation,its a type of regular notification which should show the X close button but it doesn't.
Using the following code:

```
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(iconId);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(titleText);
            mBuilder.setContentText(moreinfoText);
            mBuilder.setOngoing(false); //to make it regular
            PendingIntent pintent = 
                       PendingIntent.getActivity(context,noteId,resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(pintent);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(noteId, mBuilder.build());
```

Searched on Google but couldn't find anything similar.
Please suggest.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Perhaps because of:

"On platform versions that don't offer expanded notifications, methods that depend on expanded notifications have no effect.

For example, action buttons won't appear on platforms prior to Android 4.1. Action buttons depend on expanded notifications, which are only available in Android 4.1 and later.

For this reason, you should always ensure that UI controls in a notification are also available in an Activity in your app, and you should always start that Activity when users click the notification. To do this, use the setContentIntent() method."